# TFS API: Creating a new folder?

Tags: api, tfs

Are there any ways to create new Team Project in TFS Server by using TFS API? I'm trying to create a new code to intergate to TFS server automatically.

Comment: Your title says create folder but your question is in regards to a Team Project.  Can you clarify what exactly you are wanting to create?

Comment: Sorry, It is Team Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by using TFPT.exe (using .bat file)

CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools

TFPT.exe createTeamProject /collection:**[TEAM COLLECTION]** /TeamProject:**[TEAM PROJECT]** /ProcessTemplate:"Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2" /SourceControl:New /log:**[LOG FILE]** /verbose /noreports /noportal

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know creating team projects through the API is not supported. But you can use [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) cmd line interface to create projects.  There are a few posts out there [regarding the usage.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/09/25/scripting-team-project-creation-in-tfs2010.aspx)

---

**Team Foundation Power Tool Command Line (tfpt.exe)**

> A companion tool to “tf.exe” that offers additional version control
>   commands, work item tracking, and team project manipulation. Some
>   commands invoke a graphical user interface when run.
>
> Run tfpt.exe /? to find a list of the supported commands:

**Command   Description**
[image]